# Updating data attribute in all children with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, hover

I have a task, where I'm supposed to change all the `data-hover` attributes in the `.links` section for the correct ones, which are in the `<span>` elements:

```
<section class="links">
    <nav>
        <a href="#" data-hover="JavaScript"><span>Backbone</span></a>
        <a href="#" data-hover="Angular"><span>JavaScript</span></a>
        <a href="#" data-hover="Backbone"><span>Angular</span></a>
        <a href="#" data-hover="Ember"><span>Ember</span></a>
    </nav>
</section>
```

I was trying already to pull all `data-hover` values into an array and exchanging them (using splice method) for the new ones, but it doesn't implement into HTML code after. Also when I'm trying to change this for only the first element, it doesn't update the HTML, though the update to the variable is visible in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task is fairly easy using [`attr(attributeName, function)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function).

```js
$('.links a').attr('data-hover', function(){
  return $(this).text().trim();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="links">
    <nav>
        <a href="#" data-hover="JavaScript"><span>Backbone</span></a>
        <a href="#" data-hover="Angular"><span>JavaScript</span></a>
        <a href="#" data-hover="Backbone"><span>Angular</span></a>
        <a href="#" data-hover="Ember"><span>Ember</span></a>
    </nav>
  </section>
```

Comment: it shows errors that trim and text are not a functions

Comment: Works fine in the snippet above. Examine the elements in browser dev tools element inspector and you will see the updated attributes

Comment: Sorry, I thought I need to put values into (). Without them it's working, but I can't understand how. When function trim() removes current "data-hover" value, how does it know it supposed to put the one in <span>?

Comment: `$(this).text()` gets the text of the `<a>` and `trim()` just removes any extra whitespace from the ends if it exists

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for changing the `data-hover` attribute will be using the **JQuery method:** [data(key, value)](https://api.jquery.com/data/) at document initialization (i.e. when document is ready). Check next example:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".links a").each(function()
    {
       // DEBUG: Log the original data-hover attribute.
       console.log("Original: " + $(this).data("hover"));

       // Fix data-hover attribute of each link.
       $(this).data("hover", $(this).find("span").text());
    });

    // DEBUG: After some time, log de new attributes.
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $(".links a").each(function()
        {
            console.log("New: " + $(this).data("hover"));
        });
    },
    2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="links">
  <nav>
    <a href="#" data-hover="JavaScript">
      <span>Backbone</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-hover="Angular">
      <span>JavaScript</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-hover="Backbone">
      <span>Angular</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" data-hover="Ember">
      <span>Ember</span>
    </a>
  </nav>
</section>
```